# Finding all possible sums of non-consecutive squares for a number

Tags: algorithm

The problem is this: Given a number `n`. Find the number of ways it can be written in non-consecutive and non-repetitive sums of squares. For example, `n = 117`, you can write it in 3 ways:

```
1^2 + 4^2 + 6^2 + 8^2 = 117
1^2 + 4^2 + 10^2 = 117
6^2 + 9^2 = 117
```

I have thought about using dynamic programming, using a 2D table (each dimension is `sqrt(n)`) but I can't think of way to fill in the table. I'd appreciate if anyone could give me a pointer on how to do that or maybe another way of solving this problem.

Comment: With small tweaks this is essentially the Coin Changing Problem which has well documented algorithms and implementations. Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the question as how to approach this problem:

I see two main tasks:

1. Find any sequence of squares that sum to your target
2. Test candidates sequences for the the special exclusion of being consecutive.

You have already figured out you don't need to test x>sqrt(n).